# Detect application launch from Universal Volume Control

Tags: windows-phone-7, deep-linking, windows-phone-7.1, background-agents, universal-volume-control

I have an application, targeting mango devices, which plays music via a BackgroundAudioAgent. As such it integrates with the universal volume control (UVC).

Is there a way to detect when the application is launched by tapping the artists details in the UVC?

Alternatively, is there a way to set a deep link for the UVC to use?

I want this so that I can take the user to the "Now playing" page, rather than the main page, when the app is launched via the UVC.

**Update**
This also affects launching the app from the now playing tile in the Music & Video hub as the BackgroundAudioPlayer automatically integrates with this part of the hub.

Comment: Usually you specify a NavigationUri along with the MediaHistoryItem, but I'm not sure if that's relevant for your problem. But if it is, you could have it pass along a different uri, like when creating live tiles.

Comment: @Claus The BackgroudAudioAgents integrate with the hub without being able to specify anything. That's the problem.

Comment: Did you ever get this working _while_ the app is running? [I've posted a direct question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068995) (apologies for the cross promotion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `MediaHistory` Zune Hub integration solves this problem. It also passes the Marketplace Test Kit capability test step in the RC SDK, so that’s a good sign.

If you start from the example on MSDN, calling the following code from `GetNextTrack()` and `GetPreviousTrack()` in the background audio agent means that when you click UVC or Zune Now Playing you can get back the navigation query string you specify here…

```
    private AudioTrack ChangeTrack()
    {
        AudioTrack track = _playList[currentTrackNumber];

        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        Stream s = isoStore.OpenFile("ApplicationIcon.png", FileMode.Open);

        MediaHistoryItem nowPlaying = new MediaHistoryItem();
        nowPlaying.Title = "Background Audio is playing!";
        nowPlaying.ImageStream = s;
        nowPlaying.PlayerContext.Add("keyString", track.Title);
        MediaHistory.Instance.NowPlaying = nowPlaying;

        return track;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. It's good to know this works but disappointing that the BAP implements functionality that users must override to be accepted in the marketplace.

Comment: and I assume that it is the PlayerContext dictionary that gets serialised onto the naviagtion uri, yes?