# Responding to universal volume control "launch" while the app is running

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

If the application is not in the foreground, tapping on the track name in the Universal Volume Control (UVC) launches the application with the context information of the track (set via MediaHistory.Instance.NowPlaying).

However, if the application is already running, no such navigation is made. I'd like to respond to it in order to redirect the user to the "now playing" experience as the built in media player does.

Is there an event raised that I'm not aware of, or was this scenario not considered?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I just checked one of my apps (on WP8) and it navigates to the "now playing" page from the UVC whether the app is already running or not.

Comment: It looks like it has been resolved in WP8. Add that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [tiwahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116205/tiwahu), this issue appears to has been resolved in WP8. It now causes the app to exit and re-launch.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone OS handles the playing of the song you cannot interfere with that.
That's why from the UVC you are brought to the built in media player.