# Universal volume control navigation WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-agents, universal-volume-control

How do we control the navigation to a page from UVC? I want it to navigate to the "Now playing page" in the app when tapped, both when the app is closed and app is in the background. "BackgroundAudioPlayer" is used for playing the songs.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I came to is - writing the current song to the Now playing item in Music & video hub as mentioned in this post - [Detect application launch from Universal Volume Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159900/detect-application-launch-from-universal-volume-control?rq=1)

The value given into the `MediaHistoryItem.PlayerContext` will be obtained as the `NavigationContext.QueryString` in the `OnNavigatedTo` event. Using this value, navigate to the required page.